# Display full screen screenshot/photo preview?

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, photos, screenshots

I am looking for a method that can be used to select screenshots, but when displaying them it does in full screen, so we just slide to see the next one.

By "selector" I mean, other app wants some image chosen, and these 3 options below are shown to me.

Currently I have:

- gallery (default android) it shows tiny previews and wont help
- quickpick it shows tiny previews too
- photos, I cant find the latest screenshots at all (but it is tiny previews too).

I need full screen to be SURE I am selecting the correct screenshot...
No search I do on play store will help.
It is a too specific requirement.
So if you know an app or any way that can be used to select photos or screenshots but shows them ON FULL SCREEN or at least half the screen size, it will be much better than other options we have.

Comment: Solution of Mixplorer (my answer) deleted, as this feature appears broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an app "simple gallery"
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobiletools.gallery
it has an option to lower the number of shown columns, and that will make all screenshots bigger!